# Scala large list allocation causes heavy garbage collection

Tags: scala, list, garbage-collection

EDIT, Summary: So, in the long chain of back and too, I think the "final answer" is a little hard to find. In essence however, Yuval pointed out that the incremental allocation of a large amount of memory forces a heap resize (actually, two by the look of the graph). A heap resize on a normal JVM involves a full GC, the most expensive, timeconsuming, collection possible. So, the reality is that my process isn't collecting lots of garbage per se, rather its doing heap resizes which inherently trigger expensive GC as part of the heap reorganization process. Those of us more familiar with Java than Scala are more likely to have allocated a simple ArrayList, which even if it causes heap resizing, is only a few objects (and likely allocated directly into old-gen if it's a big array) which would be far less work--because it's far fewer objects!--for a full GC anyway. Moral is likely that some other structure would be more appropriate for very large "lists".

I was trying to experiment with some of Scala's data structures (actually, with the parallel stuff, but that's not relevant to the problem I bumped into). I'm trying to create a fairly long list (with the intention of processing it purely sequentially). But try as I might, I'm failing to create a simple list without invoking vast quantities of garbage collection. I'm fairly sure that I'm simply pre-pending the new items to the existing tail, but the GC load suggests that I'm not. I've tried a couple of techniques so far (I'm starting to suspect that I'm misunderstanding something truly fundamental about this structure :( )

Here's the first effort:

```
val myList = {
  @tailrec
  def addToList(remaining:Long, acc:List[Double]): List[Double] =
    if (remaining > 0) addToList(remaining - 1, 0 :: acc)
    else acc

  addToList(10000000, Nil)
}
```

And when I began to doubt I knew how to do recursion after all, I came up with this mutating beast.

```
val myList = {
  var rv: List[Double] = Nil
  var count = 10000000
  while (count > 0) {
    rv = 0.0 :: rv
  }
  rv
}
```

They both give the same effect: 8 cores running flat out doing GC (according to jvisualvm) and memory allocation reaching peaks at just over 1GB, which I assume is the real allocated space required for the data, but on the way, it creates a seemingly vast amount of trash on the way.

Am I doing something horribly wrong here? Am I somehow forcing the recreation of the entire list with every new element (I'm trying very hard to only do "prepend" type operations, which I thought should avoid that).

Or maybe, I have half a memory of hearing that Scala List does something odd to help it transform into a mutable list, or a parallel list, or something. Really don't recall what. Is this something to do with that? And if so, what the heck was "that" anyway?

Oh, and here's the image of the GC process. Notice the front-loading on the otherwise triangular rise of the memory that represents the "real" allocated data. That huge hump, and the associated CPU usage are my problem: [image: Screenshot from jvisualvm showing GC activity]

EDIT: I should clarify, I'm interested in two things. First, if my creation of the list is intrinsically faulty (i.e. if I'm not in fact only performing prepend operations) then I'd like to understand why, and how I should do this "right". Second, if my construction is sound and the odd behavior is intrinsic in the List, I'd like to understand the List better, so I know what it's doing, and why. I'm not particularly interested (at this point) in alternative ways to build a sequential data structure that sidesteps this problem. I anticipate using List a lot, and would like to know what's happening. (Later, I might well want to investigate other structures in this level of detail, but not right now).

Comment: Why don't you consider using a Vector instead of a List?

Comment: My question is not about solving an "engineering problem", it's about understanding the behavior. That said, I'll probably make the same experiment with other structures to see what I can learn about them too :)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this explains all of what you are seeing, but one aspect of how you are loading the heap so heavily may be all the wrapping of primitives (`Int`, `Double`) implicit in your code. Instead of making a `List` of `0` or `0.0`, why not try defining a `val` of an ordinary reference type (like `String`) prior to building your `List`, and make a very long `List` of just that never-to-be-wrapped, preallocated object? That may behave more as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, if my creation of the list is intrinsically faulty (i.e. if
>   I'm not in fact only performing prepend operations) then I'd like to
>   understand why

You are constructing the list properly, there's no problem there.

> Second, if my construction is sound and the odd behavior is intrinsic
>   in the List, I'd like to understand the List better, so I know what
>   it's doing, and why

`List[A]` in Scala is based on a linked list implementation, where you have a head of type `A`, and a tail of type `List[A]`. `List[A]` is an abstract class with two implementations, one presenting the empty list called `Nil`, and one called "Cons", or `::`, representing a list which has a head value and a tail, which can be either full or empty:

```
def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] =
  new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)
```

If we look at the implementation for `::`, we can see that it is a simple case class with two fields:

```
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

A quick look using the memory tab in IntelliJ shows:

[image: Memory overhead of creating a List]

That we have ten million `Double` values, and ten million instances of the `::` case class, which in itself has additional overhead for being a case class (the compiler "enhances" these classes with additional structure).

Your JVisualVM instance doesn't show the GC graph being fully utilized, it is rather showing your CPU is overworked from generating the large list of items. During the allocation process, you generate a lot of intermediate lists until you reach your fully generated list, which means data has to be evicted between the different GC levels (Eden, Survivor and Old, assuming you're running the JVM flavor of Scala).

If we want a bit more information, we can use Mission Control to see into what's causing the memory pressure. This is a sample generated from a 30 second profile running:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  def myList: List[Double] = {
    @tailrec
    def addToList(remaining:Long, acc:List[Double]): List[Double] =
      if (remaining > 0) addToList(remaining - 1, 0 :: acc)
      else acc

    addToList(10000000, Nil)
  }

  while (true) {
    myList
  }
}
```

[image: Mission Control Profile]

We see that we have a call to `BoxesRunTime.boxToDouble` which happens due to the fact that `::` is a generic class and doesn't have a `@specialized` attribute for `double`. We go `scala.Int -> scala.Double -> java.lang.Double`.

Comment: "and that's why the GC has to do work cleaning up in the process." I fail to see this. Any list created is used as a tail of another list, therefore I do not see anything to clean up. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @Suma When you create a lot of intermediate lists, you fill up Eden (assuming you're running the JVM flavor of Scala). This means the GC now needs to execute a GC in order to evict the data from Eden to Survivor. When you have a lot of data generated, this process will happen often between the different levels of storage.

Comment: Thanks, this will take me a little time to properly digest. In the meantime, a couple of thoughts/questions.

1) Suma asked about disposal of intermediate lists. I don't (yet?) see the part where you describe intermediate lists but I agree with him that I thought the point of :: on an immutable list is precisely that by only performing prepends like this, we never create any intermediate list that needs GC.

2) If the CPU load is purely object creation (which I can believe, as you point out the blue line isn't maxed out) then another issue puzzles: All 8 cores are at 100% Why parallel?,

Comment: @TobyEggit By intermediate lists I did not mean lists which are constructed and thrown away, but lists which are created to be part of the larger linked list implementation. Although they are not thrown away, they still generate GC pressure due to the fact that they fill Eden, and since they all have GC roots they are promoted to older heap spaces, such as Survivor and Old. Regarding 2), the CPU could be scheduling execution of the loop on any of the given threads, it need not be the same thread resuming execution each time, hence why you feel like its parallel.

Comment: OK, cleaning out the other garbage makes sense I guess, though it seems like there's a heck of a lot of it for a freshly started VM that's not done anything else. I will see if I can devise another test to determine what's being collected perhaps (no idea how I'd achieve that!). But the 800% CPU shown in "top" is very disconcerting still. The List isn't a parallel list, and I really don't see how it can be doing anything using multiple cores concurrently (besides GC) in the main execution. Well, I guess I'll want to poke around more, but your explanation seems plausible at least, thanks!

Comment: @TobyEggitt Even though *nothing* is being collected, the GC still has to run once Eden fills up, right? In order to move the data around to an older generation and emit a new ephemeral segment. 

Regarding the list, it need not be parallel at all for the compiler to schedule the time slice of the single thread across different CPUs. Think about it, the CPUs are running millions of instructions per second, and your thread could be scheduled on any one of them. Since you're running a tight loop, you see its visibility between multiple threads.

Comment: @TobyEggitt Perhaps my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611701/how-does-scala-use-all-my-cores-here/45615357#45615357) can help you clarify the misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, it has to run GC to do the promotions to the old gen. That's a a good point, doh! And now I look more closely the blue "heap used" graph from visualvm shows a linear rise for a moment, then a kind of plateau, during which two heap resize operations take place, then the linear rise continues (and the GC activity graph stops, and the CPU levels off and about 1 CPUs worth). OK, I think I get it now. I guess I was startled, as I've never created a large linked list one piece at a time (recent immigrant from Java, where I'd have been using ArrayList by default which resizes by doubling). THX!.

Comment: Side note though, the main allocation is "single threaded" so while it might get scheduled on different cores, it should be a single core at a time The GC is all eight running at the *same* time, but the graphs do show that behavior, since after the heap resize (and consequent full-GC) only one core's worth of CPU is running. Happy with that now, totally forgot that a heap resize is a full GC. Will try again with a pre-allocated heap :)